# Facebook App for adding tab to page OAuth in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-oauth

I am creating a facebook app for adding a tab on my facebook page. I am using Codeigniter Framework for that. I need access to some user info - email, education, etc in a particular page of my app. So, I need to authenticate only in that page and get the access token. In my attempt of doing that I am able to authenticate the user but unable to get the code sent by facebook oauth, which I need to get the access token. I think this is due to the fact that Codeigniter modifies the get array. I tried some ways to get the get array working but I was still unable to get the code contents.

Can you please give me a straight forward way to get an oauth token for the user in my app. I have tried to search a lot, but nothing worked.

So far this is the code I wrote:

```
$canvas_page = $page_url;
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
$code = $this->input->get('code');
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=email,user_work_history,user_education_history";
  if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
  } else {
        echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"])."<br/>";
        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?". "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page). "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;
        $a = file_get_contents($graph_url);
        var_dump($a);
  }
```

Please give me a simple way to get the OAuth done. I want to spend more time developing that app than trying to figure out OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

You may disable sanitization of GET but you probably doesn't want this.

As a quick and dirty solution you can do something like this:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $args); // $args now contain GET parameters
```